# Using nohup on Solaris 10

Tags: unix, solaris, nohup

I need to transfer a large number of files over SFTP (only between Solaris servers) which takes a very long time.  I cannot keep my PC on for this duration.  I tried:

nohup sftp server1

While the shell is open, I see files are downloaded.  When I close the shell it stops.  In ps -ef I don't see the sftp process.  The file nohup.out states: Killed by signal 15

If instead I do ctrl-z, bg, disown it works.  However this requires the bash shell.  I'd prefer a solution for ksh.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Start your sftp session as usual: `sftp server1`
- Put it in the background with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- Disconnect it from its parent with `nohup -ga $(pgrep sftp)`

Comment: jlliagre, this is pretty much it.  i had to do:  nohup -ga $(pgrep sftp).  thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect task for [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: ErikA, I'm using Unix (Solaris) so unfortunately this won't work.

Comment: Looks like it's easy enough to install: http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/features/articles/gnu_screen.jsp

Comment: I also don't have root access to this particular server :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't use KSH myself, but have you tried:

```
nohup sftp server1 &
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work.  When I put in my password I get:  ksh: opticall:  not found (opticall is the password for server1)

Comment: @anurag kohli - Do you have access to Perl with the Expect module?

Comment: @anurag kohli: Does it work if you do `nohup sftp server1` (no `&`), enter your password, then do Ctrl-z and `bg` (no `disown` should be necessary since you have `nohup`) in ksh?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson:  Unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use scp in a script ?  This is non-interactive and therefore doesnt require a terminal, and will work fine with nohup.

Comment: Chris, I could look into this.  However I don't have root access to this particular server so not sure if this is viable.